# Delete uploaded file with jquery fileupload Basic Plus

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using jQuery File Upload basic plus and it works good to upload.
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic-plus.html

After the upload is successful using the upload button, I want to be able to delete the upload using a delete button.  I can't figure out how make a delete button work. This is the code that makes the upload button.

```
uploadButton = $('<button/>')
        .addClass('btn btn-primary')
        .prop('disabled', true)
        .text('Processing...')
        .on('click', function () {
            var $this = $(this),
                data = $this.data();
            $this
                .off('click')
                .text('Abort')
                .on('click', function () {
                    $this.remove();
                    data.abort();
                });
            data.submit().always(function () {
                $this.remove();
            });
        });
```

This is where the upload button is placed in the HTML

```
 }).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    data.context = $('<div/>').appendTo('#files');
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        var node = $('<p/>')
                .append($('<span/>').text(file.name));
        if (!index) {
            node
                .append('<br>')
                .append(uploadButton.clone(true).data(data));
        }
        node.appendTo(data.context);
    });
```

I'm not sure how the upload button code works enough to put a delete button there too.